# Move elements for one array to other

Tags: c, arrays, return

I have that problem to solve
Develop a program that

1. In the main the user will enter an integer as a divisor. It will create two one-dimensional tables of integer values ​​of size 30 elements.

The 1st table will receive for values, random numbers from 0 to 99 (use of the rand function).

2. will use a function where the second table will have as values, ONLY the numbers of the 1st table that are exactly divisible by the divisor (integer divisor i.e. quotient 0).
3. In the main it will print the values ​​of the two tables.

i reached that level

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Have you actually written any code?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the comments:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // create the two arrays
    int arr1[30];
    int arr2[30];
    int j = 0;
    unsigned int divisor;
    // prompt the user
    printf("Enter a divisor: ");
    // make sure prompt is actually shown
    fflush(stdout);
    // we use scanf to read a number
    if (scanf("%u", &divisor) != 1) {
        // scanf couldn't read in a number
        printf("Could not read a number.");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("arr1: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++) {
        // we use rand() % 100 to bound between 0 and 99
        arr1[i] = rand() % 100;
        // we print out the value
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
        // we use % to get the remainder
        if (arr1[i] % divisor == 0) {
            // if the remainder is 0 then we can add to arr2
            // j represents the index in arr2 we should insert into
            // so we insert into arr2[j] then increment with j++
            arr2[j] = arr1[i];   
            j ++;
        }
    }
    printf("\narr2: ");
    // now you print out the values of arr2
    // since this is likely a homework problem I want you to figure it out yourself
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```